# Is it correct to say "Don't put your expectation so high"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

While searching on the Internet, I found that another way to say it is "Don't **set** your expectations so high", but I didn't find anything related to "Don't **put** your expectation so high". Is it grammatically correct to say it?

Comment: It's grammatically correct, but "set" is more idiomatic.

Comment: It's fine, except _expectations_ needs to be plural to invoke the fixed form.

Answer (score 6):

It is grammatical, but peculiar.  Better: "Don't set your expectation so high" or even better "Lower your expectations."

Comment: Google 3-grams would be reasonable supporting evidence for 'not unacceptable but unusual'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is grammatically correct to say "Don't put your expectation so high", but *expectation* should be pluralized. However, the more idiomatic expression is "Don't **set** your expectations [**so** / **too**] high". There's also "Don't **keep** your expectations too high".

As of writing, searching for

- `"Don't put your expectations so high"` on Google fetched about **791** results (**51** accessible results).
- `"Don't put your expectations too high"` on Google fetched about **2,530** results (**244** accessible results).
- `"Don't set your expectations so high"` on Google fetched about **1,510** results (**258** accessible results).
- `"Don't set your expectations too high"` on Google fetched about **19,900** results (**279** accessible results).
- `"Don't keep your expectations too high"` on Google fetched about **3,090** results (**275** accessible results).
- `"Don't keep your expectations so high"` on Google fetched about **2,320** results (**56** accessible results).

As you can see, "Don't **set** your expectations **too** high" appears to be the most common expression. There's also "Lower your expectations" as Gedgar suggests, with about **6,13,000** results (**383** accessible results) on Google.

Comment: Note: The number of results I've taken are from the last page, which always has the *correct* number of results. So don't be surprised when you see 6,09,000 results for "Lower your expectations". The actual number (from the last page) is about 381.

Comment: I don't think that "check the last page" approach is remotely accurate. Consider `"Don't set your expectations too high"`, certainly a very popular phrasing. I see 31 pages of results, so ~300 listed results. There is simply no way there's *so few* occurrences of that phrase on the public internet, so obviously Google is limiting the number of displayed results. For confirmation, adding a site restriction, e.g. `site:reddit.com`, *still* has 31 pages of results, *from a single site*, and I'm absolutely certain there are still more occurrences on Reddit alone.

Comment: @Bob: That's right. I was referring to the number of *accessible* results. Results that are displayed to everyone in common, or results that everyone can *see*. The number on the first page is just an estimate. Take "Don't put your expectations so high" for example, there are about 1700 results according to the first page, but there are only just three pages of results (51 results, including omitted results). That can be quite misleading.

Comment: @Bob: In any case, I've added both the estimate (subject to vary) and the actual number of accessible results that Google displays :)